# Proper PHP input for HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

Currently getting an 'Unidentified Index' error for my PHP file.

I created a form on an HTML that requires users to enter info into a textbox. It's a basic calculation, like 5X3, so the user must enter '15'. I then need to use PHP as well as an if-else statement to determine if the user correctly entered the right number. But I believe that I have not properly set up my PHP file. This is my first time using PHP, so I'm not entirely sure what other alternatives to using. I have pretty much just structured my PHP file off examples from our lecture notes. Have I properly set everything up?

```
//HTML form code
<label for="Question 3">Question Three: <strong>2 X 9</strong></label><br>
<input type="text" id="Q3" name="Q3" placeholder="Type Answer Here"><br>

//PHP code for corresponding label
$Q3 = $_POST['Q3'];

//if statement regarding a particular question
if ($Q3 == "18")
  {
    echo "Well done, that's Correct!";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Sorry, that's incorrect.";
  }
```

Well done, that's correct! //if user inputs correct answer
actual results:

> Notice: Undefined index: Q1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/CIT273/timetable.php on line 6

Comment: You have to use `if(isset($_POST['Q3'])) {  }` and put your all php code inside this.

Answer (score 3):

You first need to wrap ur input in a form tag with a post action

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  <label for="Question 3">Question Three: <strong>2 X 9</strong></label>
  <input type="text" id="Q3" name="Q3" placeholder="Type Answer Here">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
        //if statement regarding a particular question
        if ($_POST['Q3'] == "18") {
            echo "That's Correct!";
        } else {
            echo "That's incorrect.";
        }
?>
```

Comment: I have a form method above, I just decided to choose 'Q3' as my example. Assumed people willing to help weren't going to waste their time glancing over pretty much a repetitive program.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one.

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="Question 3">Question Three: <strong>2 X 9</strong></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="Q3" name="Q3" placeholder="Type Answer Here"><br>
</form>

<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $Q3 = $_POST['Q3'];

        //if statement regarding a particular question
        if ($Q3 == "18") {
            echo "Well done, that's Correct!";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, that's incorrect.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: awesome. every time I tried to launch 'Submit' my form, I have been having extreme difficulty. I wasn't sure if this was because of how I set my PHP file up or what. But still trying to figure that one out!!

Comment: so, i still haven't been able to figure out my path yet. so when I load this into my server. should I be getting a blank page? Since I haven't inputted anything for my Q3?

Comment: You can put this code directly in your `<body>` tag. and it will work good.

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve that in 2 ways

as @Robin Singh pointed 
//PHP code for corresponding label

```
if(!isset($_POST['Q3'])) {
    $Q3 = null;
}
```

OR

```
$Q3 = $_POST['Q3'] ?? null
```

that way you will have null in $Q3 when user don't input anything

Comment: ok awesome. Now this is a bit off-topic of my above question. But I created my PHP file externally from my html file. Would incorrectly setting the path obstruct my outcome? I have literally spent hours today trying to correctly set this up. I downloaded XAMPP for my server but for some reason just can't get my intended outcomes to display, or in fact even load once I hit my 'submit' button on my html form. Any idea how to fix this? I'm doing this on my personal Mac. If not, no biggie!

Comment: there is always room for mistake :)